# 3 dependent drop down by Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Good day ,

I have 3 PHP pages ('**test1.php**' , **'res.php**' , '**desc.php**') ,So I want to make 3 dependent drop down. all drop down dependent to previous drop down. So when I select an item from first drop down , all data fetch from database by '**res.php**' and add to second drop down as item . But when I select second drop down , page will refresh and back to first step and all drop down item selected gone .

### test1.php

```
<script>

function load_sub_cat(str){     

      var xmlhttp;
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("get","res.php?q="+str,false);

      xmlhttp.send();   

      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;     

            }
  </script>

        <select name="users" onChange="load_sub_cat(this.value)">
        <option value="0">Select a restaurant</option>
   <?php

         $db->setQuery("SELECT id, name FROM yh5lw_rest_dropdown where active=1");
         $results = $db->loadObjectList();

         foreach ($results as $result) {

         echo "<option value=".$result->id.">". $result->name."</option>";

        }

  ?>

   </select>
   <div id="txtHint"></div>
```

### res.php

```
 <script>
 function load_sub_cat(str){


     var xmlhttp1;
     xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp1.open("get","desc.php?desc="+str,false);
     xmlhttp1.send(); 
     document.getElementById("txt23").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;

 }
</script>

<select name="users1" onChange="load_sub_cat(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select a main course</option>
    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $db->setQuery("SELECT price,id, nameEN , nameFA FROM yh5lw_food_dropdown where active=1 AND res_id ='".$q."'");
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo "<option value=".$result->id.">". $result->nameEN." &nbsp; (".$result->price"</option>";
        }
        $count++ ;
    }
    ?>
    </select> 
    <div id="txt23"></div>
```

### desc.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['desc'] ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can write your own code for this, you don't need to reinvent the wheel for this functionality - try the [jQuery Cascading Dropdown Plugin](https://github.com/dnasir/jquery-cascading-dropdown), it's free and does precisely what you want to do. It's easy to setup, it supports AJAX, and and you'll only need to use your server-side code for the AJAX calls.